# Flickering when using animate and scroll to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.mainNav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
   var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
   if (target.length) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('body').stop(true).animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top - 130
     }, 1000);
   }
  return false;
});
```

i tried using `preventDefault()` but still flickering

Comment: flickering what exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:
- you don't need return false since you use `preventDefault()` and you should place it before any condition statement
- you don't need the `true` in the `stop()` function
- you should use `$('html, body')` instead of `$('body')`

```
$('.mainNav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
   var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
   event.preventDefault();
   if (target.length){
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top - 130
       }, 1000);
   }
});
```

But if it doesn't solve your problem maybe do a jsfiddle or codepen to show us? Because maybe the flickering is due to other elements than the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

hmm. don't see your problem here. except some minor issues with your JQ code

made a simple example. see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0fagqjL/1/)**

or code snippet below :

```js
$('.mainNav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
   if (target.length) {
   $('html,body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top - 130
     }, 1000);
   }

});
```

```css
h1 { 
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  margin:0
}
#home {
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:48px;
}
#about {
  height:600px;
  background:green
}
#contact {
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
}
ul li { 
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block
}
ul { 
   position:fixed;
   padding:15px 0;
   width:100%;
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   top:0;
   margin:0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainNav">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="home">
<h1>WELCOME !</h1>
</div>
<div id="about">
<h1>About Us</h1>
</div>
<div id="contact">
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
</div>
```